# How to escape line break and double quotes in json response from Apache Solr, which is reformatted using XSLT?

Tags: json, apache, xslt, solr

After rewriting the format of default json response from Apache Solr using solr.XSLTResponseWriter , I didn't get valid json since the response encounter new line charcters.

Here the invaid json response, which is invalid due to line breaks

```
    {
    "response_code": 1000,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "380": "A: If you have not received a confirmation email and you need faster confirmation due to the time of travel, please email our card security team at customersupport@hotel-express.com , including the following information:
1) Your Order Number (quoted at the top of your Order Acknowledgment email) placed in the subject line, 
2) a telephone number we can contact you on (preferably not a mobile),
3) your cardholder name and the postal address where your card statement is sent,
4) details of the people traveling on this booking, plus
5) any additional or supporting information (excluding card number) explaining your traveling circumstances"
        }
    ]
}
```

With default json Apache Solr Query, I got valid json, which is as follows

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "langid:16",
            "indent": "true",
            "fq": "fieldid:380",
            "rows": "10000",
            "wt": "json"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "6275",
                "translation": "Hvis du ikke har modtaget din bekræftelses email og du står for at skulle forlade dit hjem, så kontakt\nsupporten, så vil de hjælpe dig med din bestilling, og hvis du allerede har bestilt, så vil de finde frem til din bekræftelse",
                "langid": "16",
                "pageid": "126",
                "fieldid": "380",
                "field_name": "A: If you have not received a confirmation email and you need faster confirmation due to the time of travel, please email our card security team at customersupport@hotel-express.com , including the following information:\n1) Your Order Number (quoted at the top of your Order Acknowledgment email) placed in the subject line, \n2) a telephone number we can contact you on (preferably not a mobile),\n3) your cardholder name and the postal address where your card statement is sent,\n4) details of the people traveling on this booking, plus\n5) any additional or supporting information (excluding card number) explaining your traveling circumstances",
                "_version_": 1520514052354211800
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

xslt used to reformat (json.xsl) as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" media-type="application/json"/>

<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:text>{"response_code": 1000, "message" : "Success", "data":[{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc"/>
    <xsl:text>}]}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='fieldid']"/>
    <xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='field_name']"/>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to remove line breaks as well as double quotes, i changes xsl file to,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" media-type="application/json"/>

    <xsl:template match="result">
        <xsl:text>{"response_code": 1000, "message" : "Success", "data":[{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc"/>
        <xsl:text>}]}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:variable name="escaped-body">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="str[@name='translation']"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'\&quot;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='fieldid']"/>
        <xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($escaped-body)"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here `normalize-space()` will remove white spaces which will remove the problem. In-order to escape double quotes used we write a xsl template `replace-string`. So as a result i got valid json

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not allow line breaks (they are considered as *control characters*). You can simply replace them by `\n`.

Comment: Yes, But we got this response as a result of Apache Solr query. So I am looking for an option to escape this line break from solr itself.

Comment: As a "rewritten" Solr's response, right? Can you show us how you've done it in the first place?